# Error creating AKS cluster

Tags: azure-container-service

I get the following error (after about 70 minutes):

Deployment failed. Correlation ID: c08a06db-70ea-4ab8-b123-b5b9b736d27f. Internal server error

West Europe was the location of the service.

Answer (score 1):

An internal error can be a bit tricky to troubleshoot without access to the backend. Often we will see an internal error is displayed via the portal but the actual error surfaces on the backend.

Things to attempt: 
1) Try deploying to a new region
2) Try deploying to a empty resource group
3) Try logging out of the portal and back in before recreating

If all else fails you will likely need to reach out to Microsoft via a Support ticket so they can check the error on the backend and let you know the actual reason.